# react script not being loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I have the following script:

**app.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {Stage, Sprite} from '@inlet/react-pixi';

const App = () => (
    <Stage>
        <Sprite image="assets/baseBike.png" x={100} y={100}/>
    </Stage>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.body);
```

And the following

**index.html**

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="stageContainer">

</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/pixi.js/dist/pixi.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js" type="text/babel"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now when I run this there is no error in the console but nothing is being rendered. I am also unable to find that my script is actually loaded.

if i remove the `type="text/babel"` then it throws me an error:

```
Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Can anyone tell me what I might be missing?

**Update babel**

So I noticed that I was missing babel however after adding it I get the following error:

```
 require is not defined
```

Comment: you need to use bable to convert jsx to normal javascript,which is not included in your source code index.html

Comment: @JatinParmar ive updated my post

Comment: can you provide some codepen ? i am not getting how you are using react

Comment: @JatinParmar ive upated my question

Comment: @JatinParmar also not sure i can add a fiddle as i can't import node modules and its the import that is the issue right now

Comment: why need `<div id="stageContainer">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when using reactjs with browser using babel you dont need to use import ,here is how i have created simple app that run with browser (note that i am not using create-react-app ):
 app.js

```
const App = () =>{
return <h1>Test App</h1>
 };
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

you can use this component in index.html as

```
<!doctype html>
   <html>
     <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title>Hello World</title>
      </head>

   <body>
<!-- some HTML -->
<div id="root"></div>
<!-- some other HTML -->

<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<!-- babel is required in order to parse JSX -->

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<!-- import react.js -->

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"> </script>
<!-- import react-dom.js -->

<script type="text/babel" src="/app.js"></script>
<!-- import your JS and add - type="text/babel" - otherwise babel wont parse it -->
  </body>
</html>
```

i have tested it and its worked for me ,hope it will help you

Answer (score 3):

I think because you are using `document.body` on your `ReactDOM.render`, you accidentally delete the `app.js` script.

Try to use a div as your mount point to see if that resolves your issue.

e.g.

```js
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('stageContainer'));
```

Comment: Here i still get the : require is not defined from babel

Comment: This is weird. You shouldn't have any `require` keywords on your bundle. This may have to do with your webpack/babel configuration.

Comment: you might need this configuration `{ modules: false }`

Answer (score 1):

As you are using babel standalone with React, you need to configure the babel preset that you want to compile your scripts.

You probably need something like this:

```
    <script>
        Babel.registerPreset('myPreset', {
            presets: [[Babel.availablePresets['es2015-loose'], { modules: false }], [Babel.availablePresets['react']]],
            plugins: [[Babel.availablePlugins['transform-modules-umd']]],
        });
    </script>

    <script type="text/babel" src="app.js" data-presets="myPreset"></script>
```

Note that the data-presets property on the script tag tells babel to use your defined preset.

Comment: is there a more clean way of doing this instead of using babel standalone?

Comment: Absolutely, there are very few scenarios where babel standalone is legitimately needed. Since you are using node, try following a tutorial such as this to correctly configure babel and webpack for your app. https://www.valentinog.com/blog/babel/

Comment: @MarcRasmussen additionally, if you dont need anything more than a basic configuration. Why not try starting your project with create-react-app this is provided by facebook and by far the quickest way to get everything up and running. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app